# SQL sequential elimination

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-aurora

I have a table that looks like:

```
id_a, id_b, statistic
```

This table has 1M~1024*1024 records, containing all combinations of id_a and id_b. I have previously calculated statistic (float number) based on `id_a` and `id_b`, and now would like to collect list of all pairs `id_a` and `id_b` such that each has lowest possible statistic, but also that id_a and id_b appear only once in both columns.

Good result will look like:

```
[1,2, 0.0]
[5,3, 0.1]
[7,9, 0.3]
...
```

As you can see, each number in first and second column appear only once across both of them. I cannot extend this set by adding
   [6,7, _] or [5,6, _]

My solution so far looks like sequential extension of SQL request:

```
exclude_abs = []
while s < maxSize:
    a, b, stat = selectBestSystem(exclude_abs)
    exclude_abs.extend([a,b])

def selectBestSystem(exclude_abs):
    exclude_req = " AND ".join( map(lambda x: ("id_a!=%(1) and id_b!=%(1)" % x), exclude_abs) )
    req = ("SELECT id_a, id_b, statistic FROM table WHERE"+ \
          exclude_req+" ORDER BY statistic ASC LIMIT 1"
    return db.process(req)
```

This creates request that looks terrifying after first 100 extracted pairs:

```
SELECT id_a, id_b, statistic FROM table WHERE
id_a!=1 and id_b!=1 and
id_a!=2 and id_b!=2 and
id_a!=5 and id_b!=5 and
id_a!=3 and id_b!=3 and
id_a!=7 and id_b!=7 and
id_a!=9 and id_b!=9 and
[...skipped 200 conditions...]
ORDER BY statistic ASC LIMIT 1
```

As as result it takes 15+ seconds to process this query after 100+ selected pairs. Is there better way to do this sequential process of elimination on MySQL? Maybe my data structure is total trash and I shouldn't be using relational DBs to begin with?

DB is AWS RDS Aurora 5.6.10a

Comment: What version of mysql?

Comment: @EdmCoff AWS RDS Aurora 5.6.10a

Comment: Is this an np complete class of problem?

Comment: This is a very hard optimization problem.  SQL is not suited to this type of problem.  This is essentially a minimum path graph walking problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah, i see it now as such. Thanks for putting it in more context for me

Answer (score 1):

I think it is probably best to let the DB handle this in a single query rather than generating a new query for each row you want, although my attempt at this isn't very pretty.

I'm trying to sort the full table in the order you want and then use the `NOT EXISTS` against the same sorted table to remove the ones that don't meet your criteria.

```
SELECT id_a, id_b, statistic
FROM
 (SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, mytable.*
 FROM mytable, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
 ORDER BY statistic, id_a, id_b -- Include all columns in ORDER BY to make this predictable when we repeat the logic below
 ) a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT *
  FROM
   (SELECT @row_number2:=@row_number2+1 AS row_number, mytable.*
   FROM mytable, (SELECT @row_number2:=0) AS t
   ORDER BY statistic, id_a, id_b) b
 WHERE b.row_number < a.row_number AND (a.id_a = b.id_a OR a.id_a = b.id_b OR a.id_b = b.id_a OR a.id_b = b.id_b)
  )
```

If you had MySQL 8 (which supports CTEs), it would probably be prettier, since you could avoid repeating the sort/rownumber logic.

I'm not sure how the `NOT EXISTS` will scale, so possibly the following would be more performant.

```
SELECT a.id_a, a.id_b, a.statistic
FROM
 (SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, mytable.*
 FROM mytable, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
 ORDER BY statistic, id_a, id_b DESC -- Include all columns in ORDER BY to make this predictable when we repeat it
 ) a
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT @row_number2:=@row_number2+1 AS row_number, mytable.*
 FROM mytable, (SELECT @row_number2:=0) AS t
 ORDER BY statistic, id_a, id_b DESC) b
  ON b.row_number < a.row_number AND (a.id_a = b.id_a OR a.id_a = b.id_b OR a.id_b = b.id_a OR a.id_b = b.id_b)
WHERE b.id_a is null;
```

Comment: thank you for work, i'll have to test it and study carefully to understand. Upvote for now